# Validating delete on django-admin inline forms

Tags: django, validation, django-admin, django-forms

I am trying to perform a validation such that you cannot delete a user if he's an admin. I'd therefore like to check and raise an error if there's a user who's an admin and has been marked for deletion.

This is my inline `ModelForm`

```
class UserGroupsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserGroups

    def clean(self):
        delete_checked = self.fields['DELETE'].widget.value_from_datadict(
            self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix('DELETE'))
        if bool(delete_checked):
            #if user is admin of group x
            raise forms.ValidationError('You cannot delete a user that is the group administrator')

        return self.cleaned_data
```

The `if bool(delete_checked):` condition returns true and stuff inside the `if` block gets executed but for some reason this validation error is never raised. Could someone please explain to me why?

Better yet if there's another better way to do this please let me know

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution I found was to `clean` in the `InlineFormSet` instead of the `ModelForm`

```
class UserGroupsInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        delete_checked = False

        for form in self.forms:
            try:
                if form.cleaned_data:
                    if form.cleaned_data['DELETE']:
                        delete_checked = True

            except AttributeError:
                pass

        if delete_checked:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'You cannot delete a user that is the group administrator')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to domino's Answer:

In some other scenarios, Sometimes user wants to **delete** and **add** object in the same time, so in this case delete should be fine!

Optimized version of code:

```
class RequiredImageInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    """ Makes inline fields required """

    def clean(self):
        # get forms that actually have valid data
        count = 0
        delete_checked = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            try:
                if form.cleaned_data:
                    count += 1
                    if form.cleaned_data['DELETE']:
                        delete_checked += 1
                    if not form.cleaned_data['DELETE']:
                        delete_checked -= 1
            except AttributeError:
                # annoyingly, if a subform is invalid Django explicity raises
                # an AttributeError for cleaned_data
                pass

        # Case no images uploaded
        if count < 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'At least one image is required.')

        # Case one image added and another deleted
        if delete_checked > 0 and ProductImage.objects.filter(product=self.instance).count() == 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "At least one image is required.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @domino's answer may work for now, the "kinda" [recommended approach](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) is to use formset's `self._should_delete_form(form)` function together with `self.can_delete`.

There's also the issue of calling `super().clean()` to perform standard builtin validation. So the final code may look like:

```
class UserGroupsInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if any(self.errors):
            return  # Don't bother validating the formset unless each form is valid on its own
        for form in self.forms:
            if self.can_delete and self._should_delete_form(form):
                if <...form.instance.is_admin...>:
                    raise ValidationError('...')
```